# No web processes running while deploying django project

Tags: python, django, heroku

i'm trying to deploy my django website on heroku...
when i type ---->git  push heroku master(it's running fine) ,but it is not rendering my home page of 
my site.
and if i type command----->heroku logs
 then 
it's like,

```
2020-05-19T10:09:02.516378+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:09:02.733920+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:09:02.516378+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:09:02.733920+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:09:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:10:13.527798+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-animated-29167 completed 
provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:10:13.513153+00:00 app[api]: Running release v3 commands by user 
rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:10:13.527798+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:10:13.513153+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-animated-29167) by 
user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:10:13.824421+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:10:13.824421+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1a2f93e6 by user rajparmar23801@gmail.com
2020-05-19T10:10:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-19T10:16:14.542057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes 
running" method=GET path="/" host=whatwilldoapp.herokuapp.com request_id=d12ca631-fcbc-4240- 
b823-d24d2fa373d6 fwd="27.61.152.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-19T10:17:27.847271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes 
running" method=GET path="/" host=whatwilldoapp.herokuapp.com request_id=cbe42696-4611-42f7- 
aa2a-9c90912e43d9 fwd="27.61.152.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Did you specify a web process? What is the content of your [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is scale up your dynos. You can do that in the command line with

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```